# The triangle $ABC$ with points $A=(-a,0)$; $B=(a,0)$ $C=(0,y)$ is equilateral. What are the possible values of $y$?

Tags: geometry

I did the following: As $D(A,B)=2a$, then $D(A,C)=D(B,C)$ must be equals to $2a$, then taking:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {D(A,C)}&=&{2a} \\ 
  {\sqrt{(-a-0)^2+(0-y)^2}}&=&{2a} \\ 
  {\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}&=&{2a} \\ 
  {a^2+y^2}&=&{4a^2} \\
  {y}&=&{\sqrt{4a^2-a^2}}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

And hence, the only two possible points are $\sqrt{4a^2-a^2}$ and $-\sqrt{4a^2-a^2}$. Is it correct?

Comment: $\phantom{}$ Yes it is.

Comment: what you have simplifies to $\sqrt{3}a$